# Is there an easy way to modify samba shared folders?

Tags: samba, mythbuntu

I can't seem to find a way.. perhaps I'm looking in the wrong places? I tried googling but I've got no luck. What I'm looking for is some sort of easy "gui" or something where I can just select what folders I'd like to share. I'm running 11.10 atm

I've also noticed that Mythbuntu shared some folders by default, but I can't seem to figure out where those folders are located in the mythbuntu machine...

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure about mythbuntu, there is an option in nautilus. select the folder and right click menu you will find a share option. From where you can manage permission.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To share a folder, simply right click on it in nautilus, and select properties. Change to the "Share" tab. (Sorry, maybe I am not 100% correct)

To view all samba shares and settings install the gui `sudo apt-get install system-config-samba`

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
shares-admin
```

Which brings up a nice GUI:

[image]